# Creating an appointment center program, but can't save the variables to outside of the loop

Tags: java, loops

Here is what I have written so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class appointment {
public static void main(String[]args) {
    int input;
    int appointment = 0;
    String name;
    int time;
    do { 
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to ACEPrep Appointment Center! How can we help you? 
(1. Make an appointment 2. Check Appointment Details 3. Check Number of Appointments 4. Leave");
    input=Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    if(input==1) {
        System.out.println("Name:");
        name=sc.nextLine();
        boolean name2=true;
        if(name2==true) {
            System.out.println("Select a time between 1-8 PM:");
            time=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Saved! You have an appointment at " + time +" PM with " + name);
            appointment++;
        }
    }
    if(input==2) {
        do{
        System.out.println("You have an appointment with " + name + "  at " + time); 
        }while(appointment<appointment+1);
    }
    if(input==3) {
        System.out.println("You have " + appointment + " appointment(s).");
    }
    if(input==4) {
        System.out.println("Thank you for using us! Goodbye!");
        break;
    }
    }while(input<4);
}
}
```

For the line that has `System.out.println("You have an appointment with " + name + " at " + time);`, it says the variables cannot be called due to no value, and I want to save the variable values in the first loop to the original variable but I don't know how to do it. Can I get some help please?

Comment: Your inner `do ... while` loop is an infinite loop since `appointment` will always be less than `appointment + 1`.

Comment: What would want your code to print if the user wants to check an appointment before making one? That's essentially what the compiler is forcing you to consider. It's telling you that if it were to allow you to do what your code says, then it *could* throw a null pointer exception.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

You have to initialize:
`String name = ""; int time = 0;`

Also this is an infinite loop `do{...}while(appointment<appointment+1);`